# After login redirect to different page with session and after log out destroy the session

Tags: php, mysql

I made a login page , after login click it redirect to another page(index) , now index page have different page connected with `<a href=''></a>` code  , now I want when I logout the page it should  destroy the index page and related page  until user again login.

here is code of my login

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $query="select * from users";
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','fileprogramsysteeem');
    $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)
    {
        if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
        {
            $u_name=$row['user'];
            $u_password=$row['password'];
            if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['remember']))
                {
                    setcookie('user',$user,time()+60*60*7);
                    setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*7);
                }
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php'); </script>"; 
                exit();        
            }
            else
            {
               echo"<script>alert('incorrect user name or password')</script>";
               echo "<script> window.location.assign('login.php'); </script>"; 
            }
        }      
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<script>alert('incorrect user name or password')</script>";
    }

}
?>
```

and this is my logout page code , I wanted when user click logout the it should destroy the index part and all the related page with index , how to write that code ,

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) and isset($_COOKIE['password']))
{
    $user=$_COOKIE['user'];
    $password=$_COOKIE['password'];
    setcookie('user',$user,time()-1);
    setcookie('password',$password,time()-1);
 }
header("location:./login.php");
exit();
?>
```

help me please.

How I use `session_destroy()` so when I click the logout, Then it should destroy the index page until user again login.

here is index code

```
<?php require_once('inc/top.php');?>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <?php require_once('inc/header.php');
            $total_num_page=2;
            if (isset($_GET['page'])){$page_id = $_GET['page'];} 
            else{$page_id = 1;}
            $search = '' ;
            if(isset($_POST['search'])){$search = urldecode($_POST['search']);}
            else if( isset($_GET['search'])){$search = urldecode($_GET['search']);}
            if ($search){
                $all_post_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM files 
                WHERE recieved_by LIKE '%".$search."%' 
                OR processed_by LIKE '%".$search."%' 
                OR purpose LIKE '%".$search."%' 
                OR file_name LIKE '%".$search."%' 
                ORDER BY date DESC";
                $all_stmt=$db->prepare($all_post_query);
                $all_stmt->execute();
                $all_post=$all_stmt->fetch();
                $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
            } 
            else {
                $all_post_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files ORDER BY date DESC";
                $all_stmt=$db->prepare($all_post_query);
                $all_stmt->execute();
                $all_post=$all_stmt->fetch();
                $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
            }
            ?>
            <div class="container-fluid body-section " style="margin-top:90px;margin-bottom:300px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <h1><i class="fa fa-hand-o-down" aria-hidden="true"> File List </i></h1>
                        <a href="letterfile.php">
                            <button type="button" style=" margin-left:190px; margin-top:-70px;" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true">Case for Letter</i>
                            </button>
                        </a> 
                        <a href="callfile.php">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style=" margin-left:210px; margin-top:-70px; background:#880E4F;">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone-square"aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;">
                                    <font color="white">Case for Call</font>
                                </i>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="dustbinfile.php">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style=" margin-left:150px; margin-top:-70px;">
                                <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true">Filed Case</i>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-7 search-box">
                            <form  action="index.php" class="search-form" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group has-feedbacck">
                                    <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Here" />
                                    <input type="submit" class="Goform" name="submitSearch" value="Go!"/>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </form> 
                        </div><hr />
                        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>File-name</th>
                                    <th>Purpose</th>
                                    <th>Recieved-By </th>
                                    <th>Processed-By</th>
                                    <th>Adress</th>
                                    <th>Contact-No</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Update</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody><?php if($search){
                                $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE recieved_by LIKE '%$search%' OR processed_by LIKE '%$search%' OR purpose LIKE '%$search%' OR file_name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $page_start_from, $total_num_page");
                                } 
                                else{$stmt=$con->prepare("select * from files order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page");}
                                if($stmt->execute()){
                                    while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
                                        $c_id=$row['id'];
                                        $file=$row['file_name'];
                                        $purpose=$row['purpose'];
                                        $recieve=$row['recieved_by'];
                                        $processed=$row['processed_by'];
                                        $address=$row['address'];
                                        $contact=$row['contact_no'];
                                        $date=$row['date'];
                                    ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a  href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $c_id;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $file;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $purpose;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $recieve;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $processed;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $address;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $contact;?></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $date;?></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php 
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "No Related File Found Here ";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <nav id="pagination">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                        <?php
                            $search_str = '';
                            if($search){
                                $search_str = "&search=" . urlencode($search);
                            }
                            for ($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)echo "
                            <li class='".($page_id == $i ? 'active' : '')."'><a href='index.php?page=" . $i . $search_str . "'>$i</a></li>";
                        ?>
                        </ul>
                   </nav>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <?php require_once('inc/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Mean `session_destroy`?

Comment: @Akintunde yes , you are right , i edited the question

Comment: Post your index.html's code here

Comment: @GyandeepSharma posted the index page which is also connected to different different page

Answer (score 2):

To destroy the session you can easily use `session_destroy()` function. Then you have to do is make every other pages restricted for others (Only accessible logged users). to do that you can use these kind of php code to the top of each page.

```
<?php
session_start();
//This will check that user is logged in or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])
{
   //this will redirect user to log in page if he is not logged user
   header("location:./login.php"); 
}
?>
```

If some one trying to access the page without log in, there is nothing on $_SESSION['user']. So it will redirect to log in page.

(If you want mare security check session variable with your database each time)

Comment: Try to check the session variable with database each time as you do when log in (username is enough). I think it is more secure.